# KeyPressEvent stops working when QPushButton is visible

Tags: c++, qt

i have a problem with my overriden KeyPressEvent in my Arkanoid game.
I use it to control the paddle( left, right). If i loose a game, QPushButton is gettin visible and i can click it to reset the game, but after this i cant control my paddle. Whats wrong?

My keyPressEvent:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    int x = ui->paletka->x();
    int y = ui->paletka->y();
    if( ui->paletka->x() > 2 )
        if( event->key() == Qt::Key_Left)
        ui->paletka->move(QPoint(x-8, y));
    if( ui->paletka->x() < 898 )
        if( event->key() == Qt::Key_Right)
            ui->paletka->move(QPoint(x+8, y));
 }
```

Comment: When you click on the `QPushButton` you're giving it the input focus so all key events will go to it first.  You need to ensure the correct widgets retain the input focus.

Comment: It wooooorks! I just had to set focus policy on my paddle to strong. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clicking somewhere around a paddle to change the focus to the window?

Also... Your code is really unreadable, please use curly braces for if-s. ALWAYS. Also what is the point of these nested ifs. Isn't it better to use && instead?

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * event)
{
    int x = ui->paletka->x();
    int y = ui->paletka->y();
    if( ui->paletka->x() > 2 && event->key() == Qt::Key_Left)
    {
        ui->paletka->move(QPoint(x-8, y)); 
    }
    if( ui->paletka->x() < 898 && event->key() == Qt::Key_Right)
    {
        ui->paletka->move(QPoint(x+8, y));
    }

 }
```

Comment: Ye, i tried it but it doesnt help. When i click on my pushbutton the game restarts, pushbutton disappear but my paddle doesnt move.
Sorry for my chaotic code :P

Comment: Can't really tell what's wrong with just that code you provided. A bug seems to be somewhere else and not in keyPressEvent function.